# Каким образом парсить комментарии из публикации инстаграм? PHP

Tags: php, парсер, instagram, instagram-api

Появилось необходимость в парсинге комментарий из публикаций платформы инстаграма, нет знаний каким образом реализовать парсинг данных посредством языка PHP (с API или без API), если имеются какие либо готовые библиотеки или примеры на PHP, то был бы очень рад любым знаниям для решения моей задачи.

Answer (score 0):

[Instagram API для работы с комментами](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API#comment-methods)